# In a LaTeX document, how to create a footnote after \obeylines which is not affected by it?

Tags: latex, memoir

As you can see from the MWE, I have an environment called "poesia" which I'd like to be able to use. The problem is that it implies the usage of `\obeylines`, and every note I create inside of it is affected by `\obeylines`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{poesia}
{\parindent=0pt 
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt} 
  \fontsize{10pt}{17pt}\selectfont
  \obeylines
  \leftskip=1.5cm
  \vspace{2ex}
}
{\par
  \vspace{2ex}
}


\begin{document}

Here is some text before the poesia environment.\footnote{Aliquam erat volutpat.
  Nunc eleifend leo vitae magna. In id erat non orci commodo lobortis. Proin
  neque massa, cursus ut, gravida ut, lobortis eget, lacus. Sed diam. Praesent
  fermentum tempor tellus. Nullam tempus. Mauris ac felis vel velit tristique
  imperdiet. Donec at pede. Etiam vel neque nec dui dignissim bibendum. Vivamus
  id enim. Phasellus neque orci, porta a, aliquet quis, semper a, massa.
  Phasellus purus. Pellentesque tristique imperdiet tortor. Nam euismod tellus
  id erat.}

\begin{poesia}
  Verse 1\\
  Verse 2\footnotemark\footnotetext{Pellentesque dapibus suscipit ligula. Donec posuere
    augue in quam. Etiam vel tortor sodales tellus ultricies commodo.
    Suspendisse potenti. Aenean in sem ac leo mollis blandit. Donec neque quam,
    dignissim in, mollis nec, sagittis eu, wisi. Phasellus lacus. Etiam laoreet
    quam sed arcu. Phasellus at dui in ligula mollis ultricies. Integer placerat
    tristique nisl. Praesent augue. Fusce commodo. Vestibulum convallis, lorem a
    tempus semper, dui dui euismod elit, vitae placerat urna tortor vitae lacus.
    Nullam libero mauris, consequat quis, varius et, dictum id, arcu. Mauris
    mollis tincidunt felis. Aliquam feugiat tellus ut neque. Nulla facilisis,
    risus a rhoncus fermentum, tellus tellus lacinia purus, et dictum nunc justo
    sit amet elit.}\\
  Verse 3
\end{poesia}

Here is some text after the poesia environment.\footnote{Nullam eu ante vel est
  convallis dignissim. Fusce suscipit, wisi nec facilisis facilisis, est dui
  fermentum leo, quis tempor ligula erat quis odio. Nunc porta vulputate tellus.
  Nunc rutrum turpis sed pede. Sed bibendum. Aliquam posuere. Nunc aliquet,
  augue nec adipiscing interdum, lacus tellus malesuada massa, quis varius mi
  purus non odio. Pellentesque condimentum, magna ut suscipit hendrerit, ipsum
  augue ornare nulla, non luctus diam neque sit amet urna. Curabitur vulputate
  vestibulum lorem. Fusce sagittis, libero non molestie mollis, magna orci
  ultrices dolor, at vulputate neque nulla lacinia eros. Sed id ligula quis est
  convallis tempor. Curabitur lacinia pulvinar nibh. Nam a sapien.}

\end{document}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

I've tried different solutions but none of them work: is there a way to reimplement the definition of footnote or footnotetext to prevent `\obeylines` from affecting them?

P.S. I'd like the solution to also work with memoir...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some work I was able to find this answer thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57318/is-there-a-counterpart-antidote-for-obeylines

```
\def\disobeylines{\catcode`\^^M=5 }
```

This will change the definition of footnote enveloping it in a disobeylines environment:

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makefntext#1{\parindent 1em%
  \noindent\hbox{\@makefnmark}#1\disobeylines}
\makeatother
```